# Ruby duplicate an object with modified params

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby object say

```
def initialize(args={})
  @name = args[:name]
  ...
end

my_cat = Cat.new(name: 'Mittenz', age: 3, type: 'cheshire')
```

I need to duplicate it within another object but with an option to input a different parameter, somehting like this:

```
Class CatCopyist
  def initialize(args={})
    @my_cat = args[:cat] # my_cat object from above passed here
  end

  def copy_cat
    another_cat = @my_cat.dup.merge(type: 'siamese')
    return another_cat
  end
  ...
end
```

I need help with blending the copied object with a new parameter.

Comment: What is `@my_cat`? Can you post actual working code (other than the duplicating part)?

Comment: that's a typo. Corrected. The working code looks exactly the same except the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to override older variables.

```
class Cat
  attr_reader :name, :type, :age
  def initialize(args={})
    @name = args[:name]
    @age = args[:age]
    @type = args[:type]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{name} (#{type} - #{age})"
  end

  def dup(args={})
    new_cat = super()
    args.each do|var, value|
      new_cat.instance_variable_set(:"@#{var}", value)
    end
    new_cat
  end
end
mittenz = Cat.new(name: 'Mittenz', age: 3, type: 'cheshire')

puts mittenz
puts mittenz.dup(type: 'siamese')
#=> Mittenz (cheshire - 3)
#   Mittenz (siamese - 3)
```

Comment: looks like it solves my problem so I will be stopping at this answer, thanks!

Comment: The `:` is unnecessary. `instance_variable_set` accepts a string or a symbol.

Comment: Both work fine, yes. From the doc : "If the instance variable name is passed as a string, that string is converted to a symbol." I might as well send a symbol directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can override dup method to define your custom behavior

```
def dup(args = {})
  d = super()
  args.each do |k, v|
    d.send(:"#{k}=", v)
  end
  d
end
```

Comment: You cannot be sure that setters are defined, can you?

Comment: If setters are not defined, you can use `d.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)`